# MySQL 4 tables full join and display the shared column only once

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 tables which I want to fully join, but the thing is, I want that the UID will be shown only once across the board, I tried the using(uid) syntax, and to no avail, can someone direct me to the right syntax?

```
SELECT * FROM user_table, user_setting, user_score, scores
WHERE user_table.uid = 'x' AND max_score >= user_score AND min_score <= user_score
AND user_table.uid = user_setting.uid AND user_score.uid = user_table.uid;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described is an inner join, not a full join, but nomenclature aside you need to specify the specific columns that you want to retrieve in your `SELECT` clause.

For example,

```
SELECT user_table.uid, user_setting.col1, user_score.col2 FROM user_table, user_setting, user_score, scores
WHERE user_table.uid = 'x' AND max_score >= user_score AND min_score <= user_score
AND user_table.uid = user_setting.uid AND user_score.uid = user_table.uid;
```

You may also want to consider moving to the more modern (as in, post 1992!) `join` keyword based joins (and using table aliases) rather than the legacy method of specifying multiple tables in the from clause.

For instance,

```
select
   /* column list */

from user_table ut

join user_setting ust on ust.uid = ut.uid
join user_score usr on usr.uid = ut.uid
join scores s on /* specify your join conditions here, as they aren't 
                    obvious above */

where ...
```

Comment: So from what I understand, there's no way to select all the columns of the tables, specified by '*', and then abolishing some fields? and thank you for the more modern syntax, learning it as I go.

Comment: @Itai: No, as doing that would be a contradiction; `*` specifically means "all columns"; if you have constraints around which columns you want to see (or, as in this case, *don't* want to see), you'll have to specify them explicitly. As a side note, it's generally considered a bad practice to use `select *` in application code.

Comment: so what's the deal with LEFT JOIN tbl_name using(id), can I use that in any way to unify columns?

Comment: USING(colname) is not MySQL specific, and it will result in only one instance of "colname" in the output even though "select *" is used.